# Why is my cbind not conserving column position?

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have three dataframe each with an identifier as row name and an index as column value. I want to bind these three together with

```
all_indexes <- cbind(res_RNA_1,res_RNA_2,res_RNA_3)
```

but this makes the column value for `res_RNA_2` and `res_RNA_3` the same as `res_RNA_2`. Below is the head of the dataframes

```
> head(res_RNA_1)
                index_1
ENSG00000259884         1
ENSG00000166888         2
ENSG00000259954         3
ENSG00000228509         4
ENSG00000266658         5
ENSG00000267598         6
> head(res_RNA_2)
                index_2
ENSG00000123358         1
ENSG00000158050         2
ENSG00000120738         3
ENSG00000137312         4
ENSG00000137331         5
ENSG00000131196         6
> head(res_RNA_3)
                index_3
ENSG00000123358          1
ENSG00000138166          2
ENSG00000119508          3
ENSG00000158050          4
ENSG00000120738          5
ENSG00000166886          6
```

and

```
> head(all_indexes)
                res_RNA_1 res_RNA_2  res_RNA_3
ENSG00000259884         1         1          1
ENSG00000166888         2         2          2
ENSG00000259954         3         3          3
ENSG00000228509         4         4          4
ENSG00000266658         5         5          5
ENSG00000267598         6         6          6
```

When I look at the top row and do `res_RNA_2["ENSG00000259884",]` I get `[1] 50491`, so it is giving the same value to `res_RNA_2` and `res_RNA_3` as it does to `res_RNA_1`.

I tested it with below code and that does do what I expect. However, I can't find what I am doing differently above than in the simple code below.

```
> test1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),row.names=c('a','b','c'))
> test2 <- data.frame(c(2,1,3),row.names=c('a','b','c'))
> test3 <- data.frame(c(3,2,1),row.names=c('a','b','c'))
> test_cbind <- cbind(test1,test2,test3)
> test_cbind
  c.1..2..3. c.2..1..3. c.3..2..1.
a          1          2          3
b          2          1          2
c          3          3          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you actually need a merge so that the identifier values stay aligned with their "index values", so something like this may be more useful:

```
all_indexes <- do.call('merge', list(res_RNA_1,res_RNA_2,res_RNA_3, by='rownames') )
```

Without a good test object, I don't know if this is correct, but I do know that there are multiple worked examples on SO. So i used your test objects and scrampled the order of rownames to match the complexity of your problem:

```
 test1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),row.names=c('a','b','c'))
 test2 <- data.frame(c(7,9,12),row.names=c('b','c','a'))
 test3 <- data.frame(c(20, 30, 40),row.names=c('c','b','a'))
 Reduce(function(x,y) {temp <- merge(x,y,by='row.names'); 
                       rownames(temp) <- temp[['Row.names']] # put back rownames as rownames
                       temp[-1]},  # removes the column "Row.names'
          list(test1,test2,test3) )
  c.1..2..3. c.7..9..12. c.20..30..40.
a          1          12            40
b          2           7            30
c          3           9            20
```